# Inheritance in Java - 2 Classes

Tags: java, inheritance

So I have 2 classes one called 'planets' and another called 'sun'. The sun class is the parent class and the planets class is the sub-class meaning this class is going to be inheriting elements from sun class. I'm having trouble accessing and changing variables I've initialised in my parent class that I'm trying to copy + modify in sub-class.

Sun's variables: 
size, colour

```
//This is what I've tried:

public class Planets extends Sun
{
    public Planets (Sun sunClass)
    {
        sunClass.size=10;
        sunClass.colour="BLUE";
    }
}

//This is what's in Sun class:
public class Sun
{
    public double size;
    public String colour;

    public Sun(double size, String colour)
    {
        this.size = size;
        this.colour = colour;
    }
}
```

Just assume that there are other classes involved that contain more details but aren't part of the issue I'm having.

Comment: No there are 4 planets venus, mars, mercury and earth. They all have their own properties (i'm assuming i need to have 4 methods? but I didn't know how to go about that just yet).

Comment: If you cannot meaningfully say "a planet is a Sun" in the real world, you should not use inheritance in your program.

Comment: Why are you passing `Sun` to `Planets` and modifying the properties of `Sun`?

Comment: Technically Jupiter is a failed sun, so shouldn't Sun extend from Planet?

Comment: (Barbara Liskov smacks @MadProgrammer.)

Comment: In this case the ONLY purpose of my sun class is to display the sun on a jframe and the suns properties are only 'distance, angle, size and colour'. These properties im inheriting from sun so i can apply to the 4 different planets. I can understand why people would think it's the other way around but in this case no. This is literally only 1/5th of my code from both classes :)

Comment: Your design is broken from the start.  Sun and Planet should be separate subclasses of "CelestialBody".  A Planet may have a reference to is Sun, but would not be a subclass of Sun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It Looks like you're going about initializing the inherited members incorrectly.  In java, you can call the constructor of a class' parent class using the super constructor.

New Constructor:

```
public Planets () {
    super(10, "BLUE");
}
```

That will call the constructor of the Sun class with those values.

Or you can have the size and color sent in through the Planet class' constructor:

```
public Planets(double size, String color) {
    super(size, color);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can i use 'super' more than once (4 times) if i create 4 methods for the 4 planets? I get the feeling it might overwrite data?

Comment: Used in this context, `super` is calling the superclass constructor, which you can only do once, and it must be the first line in the subclass constructor. If you create 4 planets, you have 4 different objects, each with their own superclass and constructor, so you won't be overwriting anything. It also is important to note that if you create 4 planets, you're not creating 4 subclasses (unless they need to be different), you're creating 4 _instances_ of one subclass, each with different properties.

Comment: You shouldn't need to call the super constructor more than one time.  Especially if you use the second example here.  You can have any information about the planet sent to the constructor when you call it (i.e. `Planets myNewPlanet = new Planets(15, "GREEN");`  Then a new planet will be created with those values.  I would do that for each type of planet instead of hardcoding 4 different kinds of planets

Answer (score 0):

Let's forget for a second that the Sun is a star and not a planet. The more important mistake here is that inheritance work by deriving more specialized classes from more general classes.

So you would have:

```
public class Planet
{
    int size;
    String color;
    public Planet (int size, String color)
    {
       this.size=size; this.color=color;
    }
}
```

Then Sun would be a specialized instance, even if it's technically not a planet:

```
public class Sun extends Planet
{


    public Sun()
    {
       super(10, "BLUE");
    }
}

   public class Mars extends Planet
    {


        public Sun()
        {
           super(3, "RED");
        }
    }
```

Comment: My suns class already extends another class (called point in space) which has accessors and mutators to return distance and angle of where the planet appears.

Answer (score 0):

Couple things... first, it seems there is a lack of understanding of what inheritance actually is.

In your example, `Planets` extend from `Sun`, which means `Planets` *have* all the properties that `Sun` does, plus anything additionally that you've defined in `Planets`.

If you are trying to modify these properties from within `Planet`, you can do so directly using `super` (or `this` for that matter, if the property is not overridden by the subclass).

Consider these classes:

```
public class Sun
{
    public double size;
    public String colour;

    public Sun() {}

    public Sun(double size, String colour)
    {
        this.size = size;
        this.colour = colour;
    }
}

public class Planets extends Sun
{
    public Planets() {
        super(10.0, "Yellow");
    }
    public Planets (double size, String colour)
    {
        super(size, colour);
    }

    public void setSize(double size) {
        super.size = size;
    }
}
```

Note the use of `super` to indicate use of the superclass constructor. The `setSize()` method in `Planets` allows you to set the size of the superclass property from within the subclass (though, in practice, you might not want to use this hierarchy)

The second issue is that your use of inheritance doesn't seem to be very logical. Syntax aside, deciding on whether to use inheritance (is-a) or composition (has-a) and if inheritance, which hierarchy to use will be made much easier by asking yourself the question: Are all subclasses of my superclass a superclass themselves?

Comment: I think i misunderstood. I didn't want to change any properties of the sun. I just wanted to use those variables in the Sun class to create new property values to the planets.

Comment: Well, by nature of inheritance, you already get that for free... anything in a `Sun` object is automatically passed down to a subclass object.

Answer (score 0):

As we know a subclass is the name given to the class that is inheriting from the superclass, which in this case is the Sun. One fact to note though is that a superclass can have as many subclasses as it wants, there is no limitation however a subclass can only extend from one superclass.

just a note.